# How do I add two column panel after single column panel?

Tags: java, swing

I'm having trouble displaying one column layout before two column layout in Swing. Before two column layout I'd like to add a table (so a one column layout). However, when I try to to add a table in the method `initUI()`, it is not shown at all (ie. is not painted).

Here's relevant part of creating two column layout:

```
private JComponent getTwoColumnLayout(
    final JLabel[] labels,
    final JComponent[] fields) {

if (labels.length != fields.length) {
    final String s = labels.length + " labels supplied for "
            + fields.length + " fields!";
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(s);
}
final JComponent panel = new JPanel();
final GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(panel);
panel.setLayout(layout);
// Turn on automatically adding gaps between components
layout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
// Create a sequential group for the horizontal axis.
final GroupLayout.SequentialGroup hGroup = layout.createSequentialGroup();
final GroupLayout.Group yLabelGroup = layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING);
hGroup.addGroup(yLabelGroup);
final GroupLayout.Group yFieldGroup = layout.createParallelGroup();
hGroup.addGroup(yFieldGroup);
layout.setHorizontalGroup(hGroup);
// Create a sequential group for the vertical axis.
final GroupLayout.SequentialGroup vGroup = layout.createSequentialGroup();
layout.setVerticalGroup(vGroup);

final int p = GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE;
// add the components to the groups
for (JLabel label : labels) {
    yLabelGroup.addComponent(label);
}
for (Component field : fields) {
    yFieldGroup.addComponent(field, p, p, p);
}
for (int ii = 0; ii < labels.length; ii++) {
    vGroup.addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup().
            addComponent(labels[ii]).
            addComponent(fields[ii], p, p, p));
}
return panel;
}
```

Here's relevant part of creating UI:

```
public void initUI() {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }
        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
        // add table
         ui.add(createTablePanel()); 

        // Here is our control.  This puts a titled border around it,
        // instead of using a label in the PAGE_START
        final JPanel libSysSearchControl = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        ui.add(libSysSearchControl);

        final JPanel actionPanel = new JPanel(
                new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 15, 15));
        libSysSearchControl.add(actionPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        // removed
        libSysSearchControl.add(getTwoColumnLayout(labels, controls));
        // removed
}
```

And a method creating a table within a panel:

```
private JPanel createTablePanel() {
    final String[] columnNames = {"Title", "Author", "Publisher",
            "Published Date", "Pages", "Rating"};

    final String[][] rowData = {
            {"Effective Java", "Joshua Bloch", "Addision-Wesley", "May 08th 2008",
                    "346", "5"},
            {"Thinking in Java", "Bruce Eckel", "Prentice Hall", "Feb 26th 2006",
                    "1150", "4"},
            {"Head First Java", "Kathy Sierra & Bert Bates", "O'Reilly Media",
                    "Feb 09th 2005", "688", "4.5"},
    };

    // constructs the table with sample data
    final JTable jTable = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames));

    final JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel();
    tablePanel.add(jTable);
    return tablePanel;
}
```

Comment: see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76487878/how-can-i-add-multiple-buttons-to-a-jframe#comment134864941_76487878) to this question [How can I add multiple buttons to a JFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76487878/how-can-i-add-multiple-buttons-to-a-jframe) (not sure if that is the {only} problem, I've not debugged the code)

Comment: Not really understanding your question but I suggest you don't use the GroupLayout. GroupLayout is generally used by your IDE. Your code is a mixture of GroupLayout and other layout managers so I'm guessing you are not using the layout manager correctly. I also seem to remember telling you that a JTable needs to be added to a JScrollPane in order for the columns headings to display.